# get last revision checked by coverity-scan

Tags: rest, coverity

I have a number of projects on github, that are automatically built by [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org) and eventually sent to [Coverity scan](https://scan.coverity.com/) for static code analysis.

I'm looking for a way to programmatically find out the last revision of such a project that was successfully submitted to and checked by Coverity.

So far, the only way I have found is to parse the [status page of the project](https://scan.coverity.com/projects/01org-hyperscan) and search for a `Version:` string.

This sounds like an awful thing to do.

I wonder, whether there is some rest API to query the state of a project on Coverity or similar.

### Update

I found that one of [Coverity's scripts](https://scan.coverity.com/scripts/travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh) contains a reference to an API:

https://scan.coverity.com/api/upload_permitted

However, I haven't found any other documentation (and which other requests can be done).

Comment: do you have any update on this?